# query on loopback with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

I have a car table for example (color, car_id) and spare table (spare_id, car_id, details) if I search on a spare with it's id there is no problem for example:

```
spare.find ({
    where:{
        "spare_id": "5a796c436d6d0353de014d03"
}})
```

but when I search for spares by car_id the result is null:

```
spare.find ({
    where:{
        "car_id": "5a796c436d6d0353de014d03"
}})
```

but I found if the car_id is a short string :
spare.find( { "car_id": "55a" }
i will have the good result
(i hope my explaination was clear, sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Why did you not use ObjectId that is already implement in MongoDb ?

Comment: i am using it, but the car_id in the table spares is not the is for this table,
there is many spares that contain the same car_id
so i want to find all spares that contain the same car_id specified

Comment: Look if you pass the id to the query as a string or as an ObjectId, if it's a string it'll not work